# Javascript innerHTML change not working

Tags: javascript, html

I hate to come here with what is seemingly a simple issue to solve but I'm stumped, and have tried multiple solutions.

I have a checkboxes, so that when clicked they will run a function that will change the total price of the cart however I can't even get a simple innerHTML change on the textbox that will display the total price with the onclick event.

HTML/php:

```
<?php

....
....
echo "<span class='chosen'><input type='checkbox' name='event[]'
value='{$event['eventID']}' title='{$event['eventPrice']}'
onclick='price_calc(this.title, this)'/></span>"

?>

<div id="checkCost">
    <h2>Total cost</h2>
    Total <input type="text" name="total" id="total" size="10" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
....
....
<script src="bookingJS.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see the elements are all loaded into the DOM before the javascript runs.

JS:

```
function price_calc(price, chkbx) {

    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = 'Hello';
    alert(document.getElementById('total').innerHTML);

}
```

Thank you for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 4):

"total" is a field.So, try `document.getElementById('total').value`

innerHTML is for non field elements like span,div etc..

Answer (score 4):

To set a `input[type=text]` value, you use `.value` not `innerHTML`:

```
function price_calc(price, chkbx) {
    document.getElementById('total').value = 'Hello';
    alert(document.getElementById('total').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById('total').value="Hello";
alert(document.getElementById('total').value);
```